# How to output the necessary rows from the table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am writing a simple page that has a table. It is necessary to display the first five rows of the table. But for some reason, the last five rows of the table are displayed. How to display the first five rows of a table?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style type="text/css">
                table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $host = 'localhost';
            $database = 'books'; 
            $user = 'root'; 
            $password = 'root'; 
            $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
                or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
            $query ="SELECT * FROM Book";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
            if($result)
            {
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
                echo "<table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>bookid</th>
                            <th>Bookname</th>
                            <th>Authorid</th>
                        </tr>";
                for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
                {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                    echo "<tr>";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
                        {
                        echo "<tr>";
                            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 3 ; ++$j) 
                            echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        }
                }
                echo "</table>";
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            }          
            mysqli_close($link);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This appears to display 3 rows

Comment: Note that rows in an RDBMS table have no order other than that specified within a query.

Comment: You have an error. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this query

```
SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL request to

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Book
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `LIMIT 5` to your query. `LIMIT X` returns the first X rows from a table. If you want more pages, you can also use `LIMIT` in a combination with `OFFSET`, e.g. `LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5` for the second page.

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM Book LIMIT 5";
```